# MVC RenderPartial model is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried making a partial view, actually it works but when I tried to put my code in html, I always get a **Nullable** error. 
This work :

```
public PartialViewResult Notification()
{
    ViewBag.Notification = db.Notification.ToList();
    return PartialView("Notification");
}

@Html.Action("Notification", "Project");
```

but when I tried to make it like this:

```
public PartialViewResult Notification()
{
    ViewBag.Notification = db.Notification.ToList();
    return PartialView("Notification");
}

@Html.RenderPartial("Notification", "Project");
```

or

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Notification", "Project");
```

Such codes give me a **Nullable** error

Here are my PartialView

```
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Notification)
    {
         @item.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly its would need to be `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Notification", "Project"); }` But `RenderPartial()` does not call your controller - it just outputs the html generate by the view, so unless you pass a model to `RenderPartial()`, then you model is `null`, hence the exception

Comment: If you also switch to using RenderAction consider using ViewModels instead of storing data in ViewBag - that's a subject to huge magical issues happening occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use @html.RenderPartail then this ViewBag thing will not work because this will not hit the action, still you want to use it then you should pass a model object in the @Html.RendrePartial itself.

Comment: Note that your now deleted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892025/error-with-dropdownlist-when-ckeditor-is-also-in-use-on-page) was correct. If you un-delete it, I will be happy to upvote.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, I have un deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `@Html.RenderPartial` you no longer need your Notification Action.

When you use `@Html.Action` you have to handle the flow, what view will you render, what model it will be and others...

When you call `@Html.RenderPartial` you are asking for microsoft code to handle the flow, and it will do, it will provide the view you want as you did by using `@Html.Action`, you just have to fill parameters.

I guess that this partial view you want to render is a not typed one, ok then.

You should do this way:

View action:

```
public ActionResult PreviousAction()
{    
    ViewBag.Notification = db.Notification.ToList();    
    return View();
}
```

View code:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Notification"); }
```

The parameter `Notification` you are passing, is not an Action name anymore, now it's the name of partial view that you are asking for Microsoft code to render.

Partial view code:

In the partial view you have your code as it currently is:

```
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Notification)
    {
         @item
    }    
}
```