# Error with DropDownList when CKEditor is also in use on page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a dropdownlist that is working just fine, but when I have add a `CKEditor` (ckeditor-standard 4.5.7)  to handel `EditorFor` helper I'm getting this error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'OccupationId' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Removing the `CkEditor` solve this error but I do need it, relevant code (from view)

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rev.ReviewBody, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rev.ReviewBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RevBEditor" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rev.ReviewBody, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sub.Occupation.OccupationDecription, "Occupation", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("OccupationId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OccupationId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div><script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace('RevBEditor'); </script>
```

Comment: Please show us your action

Comment: Hi, my controller ?  I think it's irrelevant the error is in the view before hitting the controller post ,  the get is :  ViewBag.OccupationId = new SelectList(db.occupation, "OccupationId", "OccupationDecription");

Comment: Try to use something like: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.OccupationId, new Dictionary<string, object>{{"class", "control-label col-md-2"}})`

Comment: Thanks,    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.OccupationId, (SelectList)ViewBag.OccupationId, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "control-label col-md-2" } }) , Yes, it is  the same Error .

Comment: CKEditor has nothing to do with it. And in future do not ask a user to remove a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not because of CKEditor, that is happening because you did not give a data source to drop down

Comment: thank you, but the fact is that when I remove <script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace('RevBEditor'); </script> ,it is working just fine ...